Does the Flink Kubernetes Operator support Stateful Functions?
We are currently using Flink version v1.14 with StateFun 3.2.0, where stateful functions are deployed as remote functions.
We are planning to migrate to the Flink Kubernetes Operator while maintaining the same deployment approach of remote functions using the Python API. Additionally, we intend to upgrade to Flink version 1.18 and StateFun 3.3.0.
Upon reviewing Flink’s download page, it appears that StateFun 3.3.0 is only compatible with Flink version 1.16.2.
Could you please confirm whether Stateful Remote Functions will be supported in future versions of Flink, or if they are expected to be deprecated?
Looking for information
Error Logs
2024-09-11 04:34:27,245 INFO  org.apache.flink.contrib.streaming.state.EmbeddedRocksDBStateBackend [] - Using predefined options: DEFAULT.

2024-09-11 04:34:27,334 WARN  org.apache.flink.client.deployment.application.ApplicationDispatcherBootstrap [] - Application failed unexpectedly:
java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: org.apache.flink.client.deployment.application.ApplicationExecutionException: Could not execute application.
at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.encodeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:292) ~[?:1.8.0_422]
at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:308) ~[?:1.8.0_422]
at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniCompose(CompletableFuture.java:957) ~[?:1.8.0_422]
at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniCompose.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:940) ~[?:1.8.0_422]
at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:488) ~[?:1.8.0_422]
at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeExceptionally(CompletableFuture.java:1990) ~[?:1.8.0_422]
at org.apache.flink.client.deployment.application.ApplicationDispatcherBootstrap.runApplicationEntryPoint(ApplicationDispatcherBootstrap.java:337) ~[flink-dist-1.18.1.jar:1.18.1]
at org.apache.flink.client.deployment.application.ApplicationDispatcherBootstrap.lambda$runApplicationAsync$2(ApplicationDispatcherBootstrap.java:254) ~[flink-dist-1.18.1.jar:1.18.1]
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) ~[?:1.8.0_422]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[?:1.8.0_422]
at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.pekko.ActorSystemScheduledExecutorAdapter$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ActorSystemScheduledExecutorAdapter.java:172) ~[?:?]
at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.ClassLoadingUtils.runWithContextClassLoader(ClassLoadingUtils.java:68) ~[flink-dist-1.18.1.jar:1.18.1]
at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.ClassLoadingUtils.lambda$withContextClassLoader$0(ClassLoadingUtils.java:41) ~[flink-dist-1.18.1.jar:1.18.1]
at org.apache.pekko.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:59) [flink-rpc-akka39d45dea-b78a-40ae-8ad1-94bbfbaf553e.jar:1.18.1]
at org.apache.pekko.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$PekkoForkJoinTask.exec(ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator.scala:57) [flink-rpc-akka39d45dea-b78a-40ae-8ad1-94bbfbaf553e.jar:1.18.1]
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289) [?:1.8.0_422]
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056) [?:1.8.0_422]
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692) [?:1.8.0_422]
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:175) [?:1.8.0_422]
Caused by: org.apache.flink.client.deployment.application.ApplicationExecutionException: Could not execute application.
... 13 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.flink.util.InstantiationUtil.deserializeObject([BLjava/lang/ClassLoader;Z)Ljava/lang/Object;
at org.apache.flink.statefun.flink.core.StatefulFunctionsConfig.getProvider(StatefulFunctionsConfig.java:268) ~[statefun-flink-core.jar:3.3.0]
at org.apache.flink.statefun.flink.core.StatefulFunctionsUniverses.get(StatefulFunctionsUniverses.java:30) ~[statefun-flink-core.jar:3.3.0]
at org.apache.flink.statefun.flink.core.StatefulFunctionsJob.main(StatefulFunctionsJob.java:72) ~[statefun-flink-core.jar:3.3.0]
at org.apache.flink.statefun.flink.core.StatefulFunctionsJob.main(StatefulFunctionsJob.java:53) ~[statefun-flink-core.jar:3.3.0]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_422]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_422]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_422]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_422]
at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.callMainMethod(PackagedProgram.java:355) ~[flink-dist-1.18.1.jar:1.18.1]
at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.invokeInteractiveModeForExecution(PackagedProgram.java:222) ~[flink-dist-1.18.1.jar:1.18.1]
at org.apache.flink.client.ClientUtils.executeProgram(ClientUtils.java:105) ~[flink-dist-1.18.1.jar:1.18.1]
at org.apache.flink.client.deployment.application.ApplicationDispatcherBootstrap.runApplicationEntryPoint(ApplicationDispatcherBootstrap.java:301) ~[flink-dist-1.18.1.jar:1.18.1]
... 12 more
2024-09-11 04:34:27,339 ERROR org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint        [] - Fatal error occurred in the cluster entrypoint.
java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: org.apache.flink.client.deployment.application.ApplicationExecutionException: Could not execute application.
at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.encodeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:292) ~[?:1.8.0_422]
at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:308) ~[?:1.8.0_422]
at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniCompose(CompletableFuture.java:957) ~[?:1.8.0_422]
at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniCompose.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:940) ~[?:1.8.0_422]
at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:488) ~[?:1.8.0_422]
at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeExceptionally(CompletableFuture.java:1990) ~[?:1.8.0_422]
at org.apache.flink.client.deployment.application.ApplicationDispatcherBootstrap.runApplicationEntryPoint(ApplicationDispatcherBootstrap.java:337) ~[flink-dist-1.18.1.jar:1.18.1]
at org.apache.flink.client.deployment.application.ApplicationDispatcherBootstrap.lambda$runApplicationAsync$2(ApplicationDispatcherBootstrap.java:254) ~[flink-dist-1.18.1.jar:1.18.1]
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) ~[?:1.8.0_422]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[?:1.8.0_422]
at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.pekko.ActorSystemScheduledExecutorAdapter$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ActorSystemScheduledExecutorAdapter.java:172) ~[?:?]
at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.ClassLoadingUtils.runWithContextClassLoader(ClassLoadingUtils.java:68) ~[flink-dist-1.18.1.jar:1.18.1]
at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.ClassLoadingUtils.lambda$withContextClassLoader$0(ClassLoadingUtils.java:41) ~[flink-dist-1.18.1.jar:1.18.1]
at org.apache.pekko.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:59) [flink-rpc-akka39d45dea-b78a-40ae-8ad1-94bbfbaf553e.jar:1.18.1]
at org.apache.pekko.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$PekkoForkJoinTask.exec(ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator.scala:57) [flink-rpc-akka39d45dea-b78a-40ae-8ad1-94bbfbaf553e.jar:1.18.1]
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289) [?:1.8.0_422]
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056) [?:1.8.0_422]
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692) [?:1.8.0_422]
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:175) [?:1.8.0_422]
Caused by: org.apache.flink.client.deployment.application.ApplicationExecutionException: Could not execute application.
... 13 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.flink.util.InstantiationUtil.deserializeObject([BLjava/lang/ClassLoader;Z)Ljava/lang/Object;
at org.apache.flink.statefun.flink.core.StatefulFunctionsConfig.getProvider(StatefulFunctionsConfig.java:268) ~[statefun-flink-core.jar:3.3.0]
at org.apache.flink.statefun.flink.core.StatefulFunctionsUniverses.get(StatefulFunctionsUniverses.java:30) ~[statefun-flink-core.jar:3.3.0]
at org.apache.flink.statefun.flink.core.StatefulFunctionsJob.main(StatefulFunctionsJob.java:72) ~[statefun-flink-core.jar:3.3.0]
at org.apache.flink.statefun.flink.core.StatefulFunctionsJob.main(StatefulFunctionsJob.java:53) ~[statefun-flink-core.jar:3.3.0]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_422]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_422]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_422]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_422]
at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.callMainMethod(PackagedProgram.java:355) ~[flink-dist-1.18.1.jar:1.18.1]
at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.invokeInteractiveModeForExecution(PackagedProgram.java:222) ~[flink-dist-1.18.1.jar:1.18.1]
at org.apache.flink.client.ClientUtils.executeProgram(ClientUtils.java:105) ~[flink-dist-1.18.1.jar:1.18.1]
at org.apache.flink.client.deployment.application.ApplicationDispatcherBootstrap.runApplicationEntryPoint(ApplicationDispatcherBootstrap.java:301) ~[flink-dist-1.18.1.jar:1.18.1]
... 12 more
2024-09-11 04:34:27,341 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint        [] - Shutting KubernetesApplicationClusterEntrypoint down with application status UNKNOWN. Diagnostics Cluster entrypoint has been closed externally..
2024-09-11 04:34:27,730 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.resourcemanager.active.ActiveResourceManager [] - Starting the resource manager.
2024-09-11 04:34:28,934 INFO  org.apache.flink.kubernetes.KubernetesResourceManagerDriver  [] - Recovered 0 pods from previous attempts, current attempt id is 1.
2024-09-11 04:34:28,934 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.resourcemanager.active.ActiveResourceManager [] - Recovered 0 workers from previous attempt.
2024-09-11 04:34:28,965 WARN  org.apache.pekko.actor.CoordinatedShutdown                   [] - Could not addJvmShutdownHook, due to: Shutdown in progress
2024-09-11 04:34:28,965 WARN  org.apache.pekko.actor.CoordinatedShutdown                   [] - Could not addJvmShutdownHook, due to: Shutdown in progress
2024-09-11 04:34:28,965 INFO  org.apache.pekko.actor.CoordinatedShutdown                   [] - Running CoordinatedShutdown with reason [ActorSystemTerminateReason]
2024-09-11 04:34:29,024 INFO  org.apache.pekko.actor.CoordinatedShutdown                   [] - Running CoordinatedShutdown with reason [ActorSystemTerminateReason]
2024-09-11 04:34:29,032 INFO  org.apache.pekko.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider$RemotingTerminator [] - Shutting down remote daemon.
2024-09-11 04:34:29,032 INFO  org.apache.pekko.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider$RemotingTerminator [] - Shutting down remote daemon.
2024-09-11 04:34:29,033 INFO  org.apache.pekko.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider$RemotingTerminator [] - Remote daemon shut down; proceeding with flushing remote transports.
2024-09-11 04:34:29,033 INFO  org.apache.pekko.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider$RemotingTerminator [] - Remote daemon shut down; proceeding with flushing remote transports.
